# Convert RijndaelManaged to Java

Tags: java, .net, vb.net

i would like to convert the attached code from vb.net to java.

I already did some tries but so far didn't managed to fully convert the code.

Maybe here is someone that can help me?

Best Regards
CB

This is what i have tried:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class clRijndalManaged {

    public clRijndalManaged() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    private final String characterEncoding = "UTF-8";
    private final String cipherTransformation = 
//          "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
            "AES/CFB/NoPadding";
//          "AES/CBC/NoPadding";
    
//          "Rijndael/CBC/PKCS7Padding";
    private final String aesEncryptionAlgorithm = "AES";
 
    public  byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte [] initialVector) 
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, 
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpecy = new SecretKeySpec(key, aesEncryptionAlgorithm);
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initialVector);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpecy, ivParameterSpec);
        cipherText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
        return cipherText;
    }
 
    public byte[] encrypt(byte[] plainText, byte[] key, byte [] initialVector) 
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, 
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, aesEncryptionAlgorithm);
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initialVector);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        plainText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
        return plainText;
    }
 
    private byte[] getKeyBytes(String key) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        byte[] keyBytes= new byte[16];
        byte[] parameterKeyBytes= key.getBytes(characterEncoding);
        System.arraycopy(parameterKeyBytes, 0, keyBytes, 0, Math.min(parameterKeyBytes.length, keyBytes.length));
        return keyBytes;
    }
 
    /// <summary>
    /// Encrypts plaintext using AES 128bit key and a Chain Block Cipher and returns a base64 encoded string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="plainText">Plain text to encrypt</param>
    /// <param name="key">Secret key</param>
    /// <returns>Base64 encoded string</returns>
    public String encrypt(String plainText, String key) 
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
            NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, 
            BadPaddingException{
        byte[] plainTextbytes = plainText.getBytes(characterEncoding);
        byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(key);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypt(plainTextbytes,keyBytes, keyBytes));
    }
 
    /// <summary>
    /// Decrypts a base64 encoded string using the given key (AES 128bit key and a Chain Block Cipher)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="encryptedText">Base64 Encoded String</param>
    /// <param name="key">Secret Key</param>
    /// <returns>Decrypted String</returns>
    public String decrypt(String encryptedText, String key) 
            throws KeyException, GeneralSecurityException, GeneralSecurityException, 
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, 
            IOException{
        byte[] cipheredBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedText);
        byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(key);
        return new String(decrypt(cipheredBytes, keyBytes, keyBytes), characterEncoding);
    }
}
```

I tried to decrypt exisiting values with the follwing:

```
public String decrypt(String iv_encrypted) {
    clRijndalManaged lr_rijndael = new clRijndalManaged();
    String lv_md5 = null;
    String lv_decrypted = "";
    try {
        lv_md5 = getHash("MD5", gv_login_salt + gv_login_pw);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        lv_decrypted = lr_rijndael.decrypt(iv_encrypted, lv_md5);
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lv_decrypted;
    
}
```

This was the working code in vb.net

```
       Function fncVerschluesseln(ByVal strKlartext As String, ByVal strKey As System.Security.SecureString, ByVal strSalt As String) As String
       If Trim(strKlartext) = "" Then
           Return "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"
           Exit Function
       End If
       Dim rd As New RijndaelManaged
       Dim md5 As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider
       Dim objIntPtr As IntPtr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(strKey)
       Dim key() As Byte = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fncHash(strSalt & System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(objIntPtr), "MD5")))
       System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(objIntPtr)
       md5.Clear()
       rd.Key = key
       rd.GenerateIV()
       Dim iv() As Byte = rd.IV
       Dim ms As New MemoryStream
       ms.Write(iv, 0, iv.Length)
       Dim cs As New CryptoStream(ms, rd.CreateEncryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
       Dim data() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strKlartext)
       cs.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
       cs.FlushFinalBlock()
       Dim encdata() As Byte = ms.ToArray()
       fncVerschluesseln = Convert.ToBase64String(encdata)
       cs.Close()
       rd.Clear()
   End Function

   Function fncEntschluesseln(ByVal strCrypt As String, ByVal strKey As System.Security.SecureString, ByVal strSalt As String) As String
       If strCrypt = "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" Then
           Return ""
           Exit Function
       End If
       Dim rd As New RijndaelManaged
       Dim rijndaelIvLength As Integer = 16
       Dim md5 As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider
       Dim objIntPtr As IntPtr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(strKey)
       Dim key() As Byte = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fncHash(strSalt & System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(objIntPtr), "MD5")))
       System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(objIntPtr)
       md5.Clear()
       Dim encdata() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(strCrypt)
       Dim ms As New MemoryStream(encdata)
       Dim iv(15) As Byte
       ms.Read(iv, 0, rijndaelIvLength)
       rd.IV = iv
       rd.Key = key
       Dim cs As New CryptoStream(ms, rd.CreateDecryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
       If ms.Length - rijndaelIvLength = -16 Then
           fncEntschluesseln = ""
           Exit Function
       End If
       Dim data(ms.Length - rijndaelIvLength) As Byte
       Dim i As Integer = cs.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
       fncEntschluesseln = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, i)
       cs.Close()
       rd.Clear()
   End Function
```

Comment: ok, and what is the actual question? do you want us to reverse engineer the VB code to figure out what it's supposed to do? do you want us to run your java code to figure out what it is(n't) doing?

Comment: Anything that helps :-) . The first goal is to get the decryption working in java. Maybe someone has experience with RijndaelManaged Conversion into java ?

Comment: One thing that i think i've found out is that the key length is limited with this java implementation and a md5 string would be to long to use

Comment: @C.B. that's why you don't use "md5 strings" (I believe that you're thinking about hex strings), but bytes. Start by implementing encryption and decryption in Java, when you can do that correctly you won't be tripped up by the details.

Comment: the thing is i would like to be compatible with the vb.net application and decrypt existing values

Comment: Got it working the problem was 16 Bytes of nonsense were written in the beginning of the encrypted value in the vb code. Also the md5 was generated twice there.